# Why latest hibernate does not in the maven central repository?

Tags: hibernate, maven

I cannot find 3.5.0-Final on the maven central repository for hibernate. Also, where to get 3.6.0-Final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/hibernate/hibernate-parent/3.6.0.Final/

Answer (score 0):

JBoss have started synchronising their own repo with Maven central as [posted on the JBoss community blog](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/05/24/rsync-jbossorg-to-maven-central) , therefore `hibernate` artifacts are now available without the need to add the JBoss repository to your `pom.xml` or repository manager.

[Search result for hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-core%22):

[image: search result for hibernate-core]

To add the Hibernate Core 3.6.3 to your project, just add the following snippet to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```